# Autocomplete inserir o valor em dois inputs diferentes?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Tenho este código

```html
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">



            $().ready(function() {
               

                $("#course").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
                    width: 300,
                    matchContains: true,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    minChars: 0,
                    //multiple: true,
                    highlight: false,
                    //multipleSeparator: ",",
                    selectFirst: true
                });
            });



        </script>

<input type="text" name="course" id="course" size="100"/><br><br><br>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" size="100">
```

Que gera este resultado:

[image: resultado em html]

E tenho dois `input text` nele.
É possível notar que quando o usuário pressiona alguma tecla, a função chama o arquivo `autocomplete.php` que retorna um resultado em json.

> {"nome": "Agostinho", "id": "1"}

O que eu preciso agora:

Queria distribuir os resultados:
`nome` e `id` em inputs diferentes.
O nome ir para o campo `course` e o id ir para o campo `id`

Como eu poderia proceder neste caso?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `JSON.parse(json)` para transformar o resultado do *autocomplite* em objeto.

Dessa forma poderá fazer assim:

```
var pessoa = JSON.parse(json);
$('#input-nome').val(pessoa.nome);
$('#input-id').val(pessoa.id);
```